# Include Python module from site-packages to a file from a folder in the app

Tags: python

I believe it's hard to understand the question, so I will give an example.

I have installed the Facebook SDK module which resides in `site-packages`. Now, in my app, I have the following structure:

```
/app
    main.py
    /wrappers
        __init__.py
        facebook_wrapper.py
```

In `facebook_wrapper.py` I include the Facebook SDK module with `import facebook`. The problem is that, when I try to use the imported module in `facebook_wrapper.py` (`facebook.GraphAPI()`), it gives me an error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphAPI'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that it's using the `facebook` in `site-packages/`?

Comment: If I understood correctly I think this might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder?rq=1

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: You were right, it was importing something else. Thanks for pointing this out!